# Discrepancies on excel cell color reading and setting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have a requirement to read the color of an excel sheet(sheet#1) cell and use that color while writing another excel sheet (sheet#2).
This sheet#1 is something like a template sheet with many other settings which is used to write the sheet#2.
This sheet#2 is a larger sheet with data and the columns will be colored as per the sheet#1.
And this is what I tried in a nut shell.

Used openpyxl to read the cell color..

```
df=pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet2')

wb = load_workbook(excel_file,data_only=True)
sh = wb['Sheet2']
lst_color=[]
for i in range(2,len(df.index)+2):
    color_index = str(sh['C'+str(i)].fill.start_color.index)
    if color_index.isnumeric() :
        color_in_hex = styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX[int(color_index)][2:] # First two bytes are Alpha
    else :
        color_in_hex = color_index[2:] # First two bytes are Alpha
    lst_color.append('#' + color_in_hex) 
df.Color_Val=lst_color

print(df)
```

And this is what I get as the colors..

Color_Name & XLSXWrite_Value are columns based on the xlsxwriter
And C column I have filled wiht corresponding colors in excel sheet.
for the xlswriter, this link shows what RGB codes to be passed for the corresponding colors.
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_colors.html

And then Color_val column is prepared with the above logic.

```
     Color_Name XLSXWriter_Value Color_Val
0      black          #000000   #FFFFFF
1       blue          #0000FF   #0070C0
2      green          #008000   #00B050
3     orange          #FF6600   #FFC000
4     purple          #800080   #7030A0
5        red          #FF0000   #FF0000
6      white          #FFFFFF   #000000
7     yellow          #FFFF00   #FFFF00
```

So, what we get is totally different RGB color values.
(for Yellow & Red, it is same. White & black, they are reversed.)
Obviously, when I write the 2nd excel sheet with these RGB values (Color_Val), It will not get the same colors.

FYI : I use xlsxwriter for writing excel sheet.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dataFolder + 'tmp_12_test126.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
workbook  = writer.book

# Start iterating through the columns and the rows to apply the format
for col in range(df.shape[1]):
    for row in range(df.shape[0]):
        if len(col_format[col]) > 0 :
            worksheet.write(row+1,col,df.iloc[row,col],workbook.add_format(col_format[col]))

# Finally write the file
writer.save()
```

This col_format list will look like something like the below.

```
col_format=[{},{'bg_color': '#FFFFFF', 'num_format': '@'}]
```

So, what can I do to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to access the `fill.start_color.index` property since that is rarely used to hold a color index in the xlsx format (Note 1). Instead what you probably need is the `fill.start_color.rgb`.

```py
color_index = str(sh['C'+str(i)].fill.start_color.rbg)
```

If in doubt you can check the `fill.start_color.type` first. It should be `'rgb'`. Also, you won't need the `if color_index.isnumeric():` check anymore.

One thing to look out for is to make sure that the template cells have a solid (i.e., non-patterned) fill. If it has a pattern fill then the background/foreground (start_color/end_color) color roles are reversed. However, since you are creating the template file it should be easy to specify a solid fill.

*Note 1, for completeness: The color index is used to hold the default index 64 background color in solid fills; used for compatibility with older xls files; and used for some non-cell formatting like comments.*

Comment: Tried as per your suggestion.. But no luck.............
  for i in range(2,len(df.index)+2):
    color_index = str(sh['C'+str(i)].fill.start_color.rgb)

    color_in_hex = color_index[2:] # First two bytes are Alpha
    lst_color.append('#' + color_in_hex)

Comment: Color   XLSXWriter                           Color_Val
0      black          #000000  #lues must be of type <class 'str'>
1       blue          #0000FF                              #0070C0
2      green          #008000                              #00B050
3     orange          #FF6600                              #FFC000
4     purple          #800080                              #7030A0
5        red          #FF0000                              #FF0000
6      white          #FFFFFF  #lues must be of type <class 'str'>
7     yellow          #FFFF00                              #FFFF00

Comment: It isn't really possible to say what is the problem when the code is in comments like this. It is probably best to create a new question with your updated code. Also, sharing a sample file would help to debug this.